# Laravel form action is empty

Tags: html, laravel, forms, action

I am trying to debug a form that posts to a action="".
Once the submit button is pressed its validated by a javascript then submitted. 
I am unable to figure out where it calculates the Convenience Fee. 
I need to figure out a way to track what is going on so I can debug this blank action form.

I have tried edited the blade templates where the data is displayed. 
I have checked the controllers. 
I do not know where else to go cause there is no way I know of to track what it is doing. The local dev box I have is working correctly but the main site is displaying default values that the dev box isn't. This offsets the total in the page because its adding a Convenience Fee that should be 0. I have checked the files on both the main server and the dev box and they are identical. The page changes and becomes completely different after the submit button is pressed. I hope I have enough details.

--- abc.blade.php file where the data is displayed if the customer has any value greater than 0. The customer is set to 0 in the database ---

```php
 @if($cart_details['convenience_param'] != '$')
                    <p @if($cart_details['convenience_amount']>0) style="display: block;" @else style="display: none;" @endif>Convenience Fee({{$cart_details['convenience_param']}})<span>$<sub  id="convAmount">{{ helper::twoDecimalPrice($cart_details['convenience_amount']) }}</sub></span></p>
                @else
                    <p @if($cart_details['convenience_amount']>0) style="display: block;" @else style="display: none;"  @endif>Convenience Fee<span>$<sub  id="convAmount">{{ helper::twoDecimalPrice($cart_details['convenience_amount']) }}</sub></span> </p>
                @endif
```

--- page where you submit your order ---

```
<form autocomplete="on" role="form" id="adminOrder" method="POST" action="" class="row"> ......
</form>
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 submitbtn">
  <button onclick="validateForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

--- Java script at bottom of page that validates all the fields ---

```
function validateForm()
  {
    var numberRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;   
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();
    var restaurant_id = $("#restaurant_id").val();
    var customer_id = $("#customer_id").val();
    var time = $("#time").val();
    var zipCode = $("#zip_code").val();

    if(restaurant_id.trim().length == ''){
      notify('error','Please select restaurant');
    }else if(customer_id.trim().length == ''){
      notify('error','Please select customer');
    }else if(zipCode.trim().length == ''){
      notify('error','Please input zip code');
    }else if(!numberRegex.test(zipCode)){
      notify('error','Please input valid zip code');
    }else if(zipCode.trim().length !=5){
      notify('error','zipcode must be 5 chracters');
    }else if(!jQuery.isNumeric(zipCode)){
      notify('error','zipcode must be numeric chracters');
    }else if(date.trim().length == ''){
      notify('error','Please input date');
    }else if(time.trim().length == ''){
      notify('error','Please input time');
    }else{
       $('#adminOrder').submit();
       //alert("ok");
    }
  }

</script>
```

There are no displayed type errors. 
The page should not display any Convenience Fees at all. 
It does show them and calculates it into the total.

Comment: If the action is empty it's submit to the current URL you use to show it but with a POST method, check your routes with `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

Apologies: I found the problem. The people before me had 2 files that are similar. One of them is being used by my dev box and the other is used by the main web server. :/ 
I really hate it when people do not follow standards. 
The files are what controls the calculations and is where the invisible things are kept. 
I am still hoping to understand how the blank action works.

Comment: If the action **is empty** the form submits to the **current URL** (that you have in the browser) but with a `POST` method.